# Docker registry dashboard

Tags: docker, dashboard, docker-swarm, docker-registry

I am using [shipyard](https://shipyard-project.com/) for a consolidated dashboard for our swarm.  Unfortunately, shipyard does not support the new docker swarm.  I switched over to [portainer](https://portainer.io/) which does not display the images in the registry but supports the new swarm. Any suggestions for what folks have implemented for dashboarding their docker swarm and registry?  I would like to find out if there are any alternatives as comprehensive as shipyard.

Comment: Registry management is a feature that is planned to be implemented in Portainer in the next few months.

Comment: That would be a great feature.!

Answer (score 0):

At my company we are using the [docker-registry-frontend](https://github.com/kwk/docker-registry-frontend) by kwk, it's far from perfect but I works pretty well for our needs.

Comment: Will try it out.